# iOS 8 Safari verify server identity error

Tags: ssl, safari, ios

We have a site running on https in production. In QA we run it on https but we don't have a valid SSL cert for it. So on iOS Safari 8, we get a error message saying that "Server identity cannot be verified". The error appearing is fine, but the problem how do I add an exception so what Safari allows it for my domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can email your certificate to the ios device and add it in profiles as a server certificate. After doing so, Safari will recognize and trust the server.